# Cucumber + Capybara - HTTP request path is empty in Firefox/Chrome

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

in `env.rb`, I have this:

```
if ENV['BROWSER']
  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
else
  # DEFAULT: headless tests with poltergeist/PhantomJS
  Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(
      app,
      window_size: [1280, 1024] #,
    #debug:       true
    )
  end
  Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
end
```

Tests run fine in poltergeist, but if I try to run in firefox, a browser opens, nothing happens, and then the test fails with the first `visit` statement.

`HTTP request path is empty (ArgumentError)`

What's wrong with my cucumber/capybara setup? Is there something more I need to do to run tests in a real browser?

Comment: What version  of firefox and selenium-webdriver are you using?

Comment: also - where is that error being thrown from?

Comment: @TomWalpole FF 40.0.3. Any visit or page command of any kind throws the error.

Comment: and which version of selenium-webdriver

Comment: I would try updating to selenium-webdriver 2.48.1 since 2.48.0 had some issues -- otherwise unless you're using a proxy or something to connect to firefox it should be working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `env.rb`
`ENV['no_proxy'] = '127.0.0.1'`

Comment: For future googlers - I'm under corporate proxy and because of it env variables `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` are set. Because of it I was getting that error while running rails system test

Comment: NB. I've also found that `no_proxy` needs to at least _start_ with localhost, so if you're _appending_ it and it's not working, that might be your problem as well.